# Input radio checking

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to set the Input called iva displayed only when #azienda is selected but i don't understand why the code just doesn't set the display to block
This is the code:

```
<style>
    .iva {
        display: none;
    }

    #azienda:checked~#iva {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
 

 <div class="rad">
        <input type="radio" id="azienda" name="radio" value="Azienda/Impresa/Società">
        <label for="azienda"> Azienda/Impresa/Società </label>

 </div>
 <input type="number" class="iva" name="iva" id="iva" placeholder="Inserire P.IVA...">
```

I'll give an hug at everyone who will help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You swiched from class to id with iva :)

```html
<style>
    .iva {
        display: none;
    }

    #azienda:checked ~ .iva {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
 

 <div class="rad">
        <input type="radio" id="azienda" name="radio" value="Azienda/Impresa/Società">
        <label for="azienda"> Azienda/Impresa/Società </label>
 <input type="number" class="iva" name="iva" id="iva" placeholder="Inserire P.IVA...">
 </div>
```

Comment: move the <input type="number" class="iva" name="iva" id="iva" placeholder="Inserire P.IVA..."> into div class="rad"

Comment: it must have to stay outside the rad, because rad is a flex class, i cut the useless things

Comment: Then i think you can't do this functionality with css only, you need to use js